# Use a specific value in summarise (dplyr) without filtering it out

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compare a new algorithm result versus an old one. I need to know approximately how many days of a difference the new algorithm has in predicting a "D" versus the old one.

I can't seem to figure out how to point to the first row (day) that contains a 'D'  (min(day) and new == 'D') without filtering (I was able to grab the row using a double filter due to the grouping, but not use it). I want to use it in `summarise` using `dplyr` which is why I have included pseudo code similar to where i am currently at in my own dataset. 
In my data there are groups of varying length (number of days) for each ID, which is why I made groups of different lengths in the example.

```r
library(dplyr)

id = c(123,123,123,123,123,456,456,456,456)
old = c('S','S','S','S','D','S','S','D','D')
new = c('S','S','D','D','D','S','D','D','D')
day = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
data = data.frame(id,old,new,day)
data
#>    id old new day
#> 1 123   S   S   1
#> 2 123   S   S   2
#> 3 123   S   D   3
#> 4 123   S   D   4
#> 5 123   D   D   5
#> 6 456   S   S   1
#> 7 456   S   D   2
#> 8 456   D   D   3
#> 9 456   D   D   4

d = data %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  arrange(day,.by_group=T)%>%
  add_tally(new=='S',name='S')%>%
  add_tally(new=='D',name='D')%>%
  group_by(id,S,D)
  # summarise(diff = (day of 1st old D) - (day of 1st new D) )


#Expected Outcome
ido = c(123,456)
S = c(2,1)
D = c(3,3)
diff = c(2,1)


outcome = data.frame(ido,S,D,diff)
outcome
#>   ido S D diff
#> 1 123 2 3    2
#> 2 456 1 3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `id` and count the occurrence of `'S'` and `'D'` and the difference between first occurrence of `old` and `new` `'D'`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(S = sum(new == 'S'), 
            D = sum(new == 'D'), 
            diff = which.max(old == 'D') - which.max(new == 'D'))
            #OR if there could be id without D use
            #diff = which(old == 'D')[1] - which(new == 'D')[1])

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     id     S     D  diff
#  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1   123     2     3     2
#2   456     1     3     1
```

Comment: thank you !! such an elegant solution . can you explain a bit more about why logically it is which.max() instead of which.min() ?

Comment: `old == 'D'` gives a logical vector with TRUE/FALSE values. By using `which.max` we get position of first TRUE value in the vector. Try these examples `which.max(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)` and  `which.max(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)` . If you notice it returns position of first TRUE value. We use the same logic here.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider` after `summarise`ing to get the frequency count after creating a column to take the difference between the 'day' based on the first occurence of 'D' in both 'old' and 'new' columnss

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  group_by(diff = day[match("D", old)] - day[match("D", new)],
       new, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = new, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     id  diff     D     S
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1   123     2     3     2
#2   456     1     3     1
```